# Show YUI Pie Chart when no data returned in datasource

Tags: javascript, yui

Unlike the other charts in YUI, such as the Line Chart, the pie-chart does not display an empty outline of the chart when no data is available. Instead nothing displays at all - just a blank space.

Is there a way to get the pie chart to display when no data is available?

I am constructing the chart to pull the data from a datasource, polling at certain intervals.

```
this.chart = new YAHOO.widget.PieChart(id + '_c', this.datasource, {
        categoryField: categoryField,
        dataField: dataField,
        polling: interval * 1000,
        wmode: 'opaque',
        style: {
            background: { color: '#fdfdfd' },
            legend: { display: 'right' }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this is to override a method called onBeforeCallback on the live datasource. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.DataSourceBase.html#method_doBeforeCallback

> Overridable method gives implementers access to the original full response and
>    the parsed response (parsed against the given schema) before the data
>    is added to the cache (if applicable) and then sent back to callback function.
>    This is your chance to access the raw response and/or populate the parsed
>    response with any custom data.

This allows you to change the data before sending it to the chart. If it is empty then I can add a dummy "No Activity" entry.

```
this.datasource.doBeforeCallback = function(oRequest, oFullResponse, oParsedResponse, oCallback) {
    if (!oParsedResponse.results || oParsedResponse.results.length < 1) {
       oParsedResponse.results = new Array({ "name": "No Activity", "count": "0" });
    }   
    return oParsedResponse;
 };
```